# Best way to import a custom svg icon and display it

Tags: material-ui

I have to import a custom svg icon and use it as a button within my application

What I have been doing it is,

```
import high from '../img/high.svg';

const styles = theme => ({
 icon: {
    color: red[800],
    height: '15px',
    width: '15px',
    cursor: 'pointer'
  }

});

<IconButton><CardMedia image={high} className={classes.icon}/></IconButton>
```

But this does not behave like a button and I do not get the hand symbol for onClick. What is the best way to display the icon as a button?

Answer (score 0):

Do a styled component that is styled s a span

```
interface IconProps {
    color: 'blue' | 'red' | 'green';
    size: string;
    margin: string;
}

export const Icon = styled.span<IconProps>`
    color: ${props => props.color || '#000000'};
    font-size: ${props => props.size || ''};
    margin: ${props => props.margin || null};
    cursor: pointer;
`;
```

You do not have to use props like I have, but this works fine for me. spans are very useful when forcing styling on to things like text and SVGs.

#### Example

```
<Icon size="150px" color="green">
    <i className="fab fa-fort-awesome-alt"/>
</Icon>
```

NOTE: I do use typescript. You may not need to use an interface if you dont use props. I just left it there as part of my example I have done.